# StreamPlot using NDSolve gives error messages

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, replacement, warning-messages

```
StreamPlot[{x[0], x'[0]} /. 
  NDSolve[{x''[t] ==  1, x'[0] == v0, x[0] == x0}, {x, x'}, {t, 0, 1}],
 {x0, -2, 2}, {v0, -2, 2}]
```

The above code gives me the errors

> NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition x0 is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{(x^[Prime][Prime])[t]==1,(x^[Prime])[0]==v0,x[0]==x0},{x,x^[Prime]},{t,0,1}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
>
> NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition x0 is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{(x^[Prime][Prime])[t]==1,(x^[Prime])[0]==v0,x[0]==x0},{x,x^[Prime]},{t,0,1}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

While the code still produces the plot that I want, is it possible to get rid of the error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same idea a belisarius but moving the entire first argument into a separate function, while also localizing `x`:

```
fn[x0_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{x},
  {x[0], x'[0]} /. NDSolve[{x''[t] == 1, x'[0] == v0, x[0] == x0}, {x, x'}, {t, 0, 1}]
 ]

StreamPlot[fn[x0, v0], {x0, -2, 2}, {v0, -2, 2}]
```

No errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[v0_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ] := 
                 NDSolve[{x''[t] == 1, x'[0] == v0, x[0] == x0}, {x, x'}, {t, 0, 1}]
StreamPlot[{x[0], x'[0]} /. f[v0, x0], {x0, -2, 2}, {v0, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Got rid of the NDSolve errors but still gives me
ReplaceAll::reps: {f[v0,x0]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {f[v0,x0]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

Answer (score 1):

I think you use `StreamPlot` incorrectly. Let you have a differential equation

```
x''[t] == f[x[t],x'[t]]
```

In your particular case

```
f[x_,v_] := 1;
```

`StreamPlot` plots streams based on the vector field. In our case

```
StreamPlot[{dx,dv},{x,-2,2},{-2,2}]
```

Here `dx` and `dv` is the time derivatives of `x` and `v` respectively. By definition `dx=v` and `dv=f[x,v]`. Therefore, the command must be

```
StreamPlot[{v, f[x,v]}, {x, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Another example: phase diagram of a pendulum

```
f[x_, v_] := -Sin[x];
StreamPlot[{v, f[x, v]}, {x, -5, 5}, {v, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: The point is I want to StreamPlot an arbitrary differential equation and not get the error messages above.

Comment: @Felix If you have differential equation like `x''[t]=f[x,x']` then you can use `StreamPlot[{v,f[x,v]},...]`. The first argument of `StreamPlot` is the vector field, not coordinates.

Comment: Regardless of how StreamPlot is normally used, I want to have it plot {x[t], x'[t]}, where x and x' are the solutions to some differential equation.

Comment: @Felix I see your problem. I update my answer. I hope now it is more helpful.